# how to display a title on a calendar heatmap using calplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, calendar

I am trying to save a calplot image but I can't seem to display the title. Following the [documentation](https://calplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I need to use the property: **suptitle**.

```
import calplot
import pylab
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(sum(map(ord, 'calplot')))
import pandas as pd
all_days = pd.date_range('1/1/2019', periods=730, freq='D')
days = np.random.choice(all_days, 500)
events = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(days)), index=days)
calplot.calplot(
    events, 
    figsize=(20,4),
    suptitle='lorem ipsum',
    cmap='Spectral_r',
    )
pylab.savefig('foo.png')
```

Above is the minimal code found in the documentation. I am using **pylab** to save the image on my drive [image: Calplot image]

I can barely notice the title. How can I show the title?
I am using Windows and Continuum Anaconda as stack

Comment: The title's there, it's just getting mostly trimmed off since you specified a small figure height.

Comment: I tried other alternative. When I tried `figsize=(10,15),` and `figsize=(25,4),` but none of them show the title. On the documentation they mentioned : Size of figure for the plot. (float, float). I suspect that is because of me using Pylab to save the image.

Comment: Does using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.tight_layout()` help? Also, do note that using [pylab is strongly discouraged](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#module-pylab).

Comment: Unfortunately adding `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.tight_layout()`. thanks for sharing the link for pylab. i didn't know that. I might create another question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the font size

```
fontsize=20


import calplot
import pylab
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(sum(map(ord, 'calplot')))
import pandas as pd
all_days = pd.date_range('1/1/2019', periods=730, freq='D')
days = np.random.choice(all_days, 500)
events = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(days)), index=days)

fig = calplot.calplot(
    events, 
    figsize=(20,4),
    cmap='Spectral_r',
    )
fig.suptitle('lorem ipsum', fontsize=20)
pylab.savefig('foo.png')
```

Updated with `fig` defined

Comment: Thanks but adding `fontsize=20` inside the `calplot.calplot(...)` gives me this error  `AttributeError: QuadMesh.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fontsize'`

Comment: Ah, Sorry its not supported you can use the suptitle function.                                      `fig.suptitle('lorem ipsum', fontsize=20)
pylab.savefig('foo.png')`

Comment: No worrries! May I know where the object `fig` comes from?

Comment: When the calplot function is run, it generates a Figure object and assigns it to the fig variable. This Figure object is what's used to add a title to the plot using its suptitle method. The first argument for the suptitle method is the text of the title you want to add, and there are additional optional arguments like fontsize that can be used to control the size of the title text.

Comment: Ok I see. But when I added `fig.suptitle('lorem ipsum', fontsize=20)` right have the `calplot.calplot(...)` function I got this error  `NameError: name 'fig' is not defined`

Comment: Ok... :) Here you go ```import calplot
import pylab
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(sum(map(ord, 'calplot')))
import pandas as pd
all_days = pd.date_range('1/1/2019', periods=730, freq='D')
days = np.random.choice(all_days, 500)
events = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(days)), index=days)

fig = calplot.calplot(
    events, 
    figsize=(20,4),
    cmap='Spectral_r',
    )
fig.suptitle('lorem ipsum', fontsize=20)
pylab.savefig('foo.png')
```

Comment: So you need to define it.. :) Sorry about the formatting, i can only use the comment section.

Comment: Ok I see. Can you add this as your answer so that I can vote= https://gist.github.com/guinslym/02e3af349bdbadb4e0e749aa9b4bda55

Comment: Updated answer. Enjoy! :) @G20map